# I can't change C++ version in VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I want to change C++ standard to C++20. I wrote `"C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": "c++20"` in **setting.json** and `"cppStandard": "c++20"`,
in  **c_cpp_properties.json**, but when I run this code

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){ 
   std::cout << __cplusplus;
}
```

my output is: 201402.

What I need to do to change my C++ version in VS Code?

Comment: Aren't those settings just changing how VS Code _interprets_ the code, for things like syntax highlighting etc.? I suspect you need to look at what you're using to _compile_ the code: you need to tell _it_ to use C++20.

Comment: Take a look at `tasks.json`. You need to specify a language setting (`-std=...`) in the `command` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_build-helloworldcpp) link on configuring the `tasks.json` file. For your case, you'll need to add the `-std=c++2a` in the `args` variable.